I would like to have a subscript in the numeration of equations after the parentheses
I am writing a pretty extensive Latex article and I have many equations. I would like if, when repeating an equation, it would show up as (eq number)_r. I present an MWE
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}

I present to you my first equation

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Newton_second_law}
    \vec{F}=m\vec{a}
\end{equation}

and here is my second equation

\begin{equation}
    \vec{v}=\vec{v}_0+\vec{a}t
\end{equation}

now imagine I want to repeat the first equation, it would look something like this

\begin{equation}
    \vec{F}=m\vec{a} \tag{\ref{eq:Newton_second_law}}_r
\end{equation}

\end{document}



This, instead of putting the _r where I'd want it to be, which would be located like this (1.1)_r, it locates it after the \vec{a}, resulting in the same as doing
\begin{equation}
    \vec{F}=m\vec{a}_r \tag{\ref{eq:Newton_second_law}}
\end{equation}

How can I make the r appear where I want it to?

You need nothing special: \tag* allows you to specify every detail for the tag.
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\newcommand{\repeq}[1]{%
  \tag*{\normalfont(\ref{#1})\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsubscript{r}}}%
}

\begin{document}

I present to you my first equation
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Newton_second_law}
    \vec{F}=m\vec{a}
\end{equation}
and here is my second equation
\begin{equation}
    \vec{v}=\vec{v}_0+\vec{a}t
\end{equation}

Now imagine I want to repeat the first equation, it would look something like this
\begin{equation}
    \vec{F}=m\vec{a} \repeq{eq:Newton_second_law}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

I chose to move the “repetition mark” in the margin.


Declare a new tag form using mathtools via \newtagform{<name>}[<inner_format>]{<left>}{<right>}. Here you specify the <name> of the new format, any formatting that needs to be applied to the numbering (optional), as well as the <left> and <right> bracing.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newtagform{recalleqnum}{(}{)${}_r$}% New tag form for recalling equation numbers

\NewDocumentEnvironment{requation}{}{%
  \usetagform{recalleqnum}% Use recall equation number tag form
  \begin{equation}% Regular equation
}{
  \end{equation}%
}

\begin{document}

I present to you my first equation
\begin{equation}
  \vec{F} = m \vec{a}
  \label{eq:Newton_second_law}
\end{equation}

Now imagine I want to repeat the first equation, it would look something like this
\begin{requation}
  \vec{F} = m \vec{a} \tag{\ref{eq:Newton_second_law}}
\end{requation}
and here is my second equation
\begin{equation}
  \vec{v} = \vec{v}_0 + \vec{a} t
\end{equation}

\end{document}

For convenience, also define requation for a recalled equation that selected the newly-defined tag form (\usetagform{recalleqnum}). Since the environment necessarily limits the scope, the original tag form is restored after \end{requation}.
Here are some more options for tag forms and their associated output:

\newtagform{recalleqnum}{(}{)\textsubscript{r}}% Text subscript


\newtagform{recalleqnum}{(}{)\rlap{${}_r$}}% Overlap into margin


Can you use \begin and \end inside the definitions when using \NewDocumentEnvironment (unlike \newenvironment)?

Another question has arisen (which I might consider posting separately)...is there any way to make it when you reference an equation it references in a way different than what Latex has it predetermined to? i.e.: instead of showing 5.2 when your reference equation 5.2, it showing as \textcolor{blue}{Eq.(5.2)} when referencing it.

@Rubén: Yes, some packages provide that functionality, but you can also define \eqref (provided by amsmath). See this code/update that provides this output.
